# Where to put my AJAX code

Tags: javascript, ajax

I implemented a little AJAX-based application, and now I got more than 500 lines of AJAX code. So I want to know where is the best place to put this code ?
To keep my application easy to maintain.

Thank you.

J. BENOIT.

Comment: For free source code consider `github` or `gitorious`

Comment: This is embedded in a webpage. I mean should I put it in an external file or something like that ? Because, this AJAX code use JQuery, and I use many references to the DOM objects through $("")

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inline+javascript+external

Comment: maybe you'd better seperate JavaScript code from html and include it with <script src="yourscript.js"> tag. furthermore, separate common utility code and app code for easy maintainance

Answer (score 2):

You shuould create a file called say `filename.js` and write your ajax code there and just include that js file into your html page.It is proper way and every one should do this since it look nice and professional